# Not able Iterator through javaRDD

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am trying to iterate through the RDD and applying some logic on each row and send it to API.

But the RDD is not going inside the while loop.

```
if (dataFrame.toJSON().toJavaRDD().take(1).size() > 0) {

    System.out.println("jsonString:#######");

    // System.out.println(dataFrame.toJSON().toJavaRDD().take(1));

    dataFrame.toJSON().toJavaRDD().foreachPartition(new VoidFunction<Iterator<String>>() {
      private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;               
   @Override
    public void call(Iterator < String > jsonString) throws Exception {
      System.out.println("#######");

      while (jsonString.hasNext()) {
        final String str = jsonString.next();
        if (str != null && !str.equals("")) {

          System.out.println("jsonString:" + jsonString);


        }

      }

    }
  });
}
```

Comment: why do you say that "the RDD is not going inside the while loop"? Does it print "#######" but not "jsonString:...." ?? I tried your code on some dataframe of mine and it works...

Comment: It’s printing ### but not the jsonstring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me

```
if (dataFrame.take(1).length > 0) {
    Iterator<String> itt = dataFrame.toJSON().toJavaRDD().collect().iterator();
    while(itt.hasNext()) { 
        String field = itt.next();
        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(field);
        System.out.println("jsonString:" + jsonResponse );

}
```

Answer (score 2):

in case it helps, here is the program I used to test your case.

```java
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;

public class StackOverflow20190326_2 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("StackOverflow20190326").master("local").getOrCreate();

        // generate a dummy 2-liner dataset
        Dataset<Row> ds = spark.sql("select 1 as idx, 'this is line 1' as value union select 2 as idx, 'This is the second line' as value");

        test(ds);

        spark.stop();

    }

    private static void test(Dataset<Row> dataFrame) {

        JavaRDD<String> javaRDD = dataFrame.toJSON().toJavaRDD();
        if (javaRDD.take(1).size() > 0) {

            System.out.println("jsonString:#######");

            javaRDD.foreachPartition(jsonString -> {
                System.out.println("#######" + jsonString);

                while (jsonString.hasNext()) {
                    final String str = jsonString.next();
                    if (str != null && !str.equals("")) {

                        System.out.println("jsonString:" + str);

                    }

                }

            });
        }
    }
}
```

The output is as follows :

```
    jsonString:#######
    #######IteratorWrapper(empty iterator)
    #######IteratorWrapper(empty iterator)
    #######IteratorWrapper(empty iterator)
    #######IteratorWrapper(empty iterator)
    #######IteratorWrapper(empty iterator)
    #######IteratorWrapper(empty iterator)
    #######IteratorWrapper(empty iterator)
    #######IteratorWrapper(empty iterator)
    #######IteratorWrapper(empty iterator)
    #######IteratorWrapper(empty iterator)
    #######IteratorWrapper(empty iterator)
    #######IteratorWrapper(empty iterator)
    #######IteratorWrapper(empty iterator)
    #######IteratorWrapper(empty iterator)
    #######IteratorWrapper(empty iterator)
    #######IteratorWrapper(empty iterator)
    #######IteratorWrapper(non-empty iterator)
    jsonString:{"idx":1,"value":"this is line 1"}
    #######IteratorWrapper(non-empty iterator)
    jsonString:{"idx":2,"value":"This is the second line"}
```

As you can see, there are many empty partitions, but the two initial lines get output well.

I am using spark 2.4, as you can see from maven's pom.xml :

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.borgoltz.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-client</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>


    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-parent_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

**Last but not least**

Are you running in local mode? Because otherwise the closure in the `.foreachPartition()` call may be called on remote executors, so the `println`s will be output on other machines that the one running the driver...
A simple way to verify is to check the logs on the executors or to replace the System.out.println by a write to the HDFS for example...

HTH!

Comment: Thanks for the  effort @Highbrainer I am using Spark 1.6 and still having issue :(